# Sequelize-Oracle how we put maxRows more than 100

Tags: node.js

How do we put maxRows more than 100 inside in package sequelize-oracle?

```
Import Sequelizeoracle from 'sequelize-oracle'
```

Comment: Which fork are you using?

Comment: Using sequelize-oracle package . It supports 100 rows